# Playing 30 sound effects at the same time repeatedly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to play about 30 piano notes at the same time in my XNA application on Windows Phone 7.
I have imported and loaded the wave files like below

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        sound3 = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("1");
        sound5 = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("3");
        sound6 = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("4");
        sound7 = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("5");
        sound8 = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("6");

    }
```

Every sound effect file is less than a second, so I'm trying to play all of them at the same time. I play them using a for loop which runs every second.(So at every loop 30 sounds will be played then it goes on and plays the same 30 sounds each second)
It works fine for a few seconds but suddenly it stops playing any sound (The loop is still working) then again starts working for once or twice and again stops working . It also sometimes makes some bad noises as if the audio system cant support too many sounds to be play at a time.

I'm not sure how I can solve the problem , if its a buffer problem or threads.

Comment: You could try to explicitly stop the sounds first when you replay them. Maybe the buffer is still in use somewhere and a new one is created each time.

Comment: I tried that by disposing them in my unload contents method, (dispose method cant be used anywhere else), I also couldn't find any stop method. It doesn't work !

Comment: No, I don't mean disposing of them. Try to create an instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.createinstance.aspx) and play this one instead of the `SoundEffect`.

Comment: I'm sure you realize this but just to make sure... Your sounds are not numbered properly :p. It will be easier to keep track of them if sound3 was actually equal to "3".

Comment: I tried the instance one yesterday , it doesn't allow me to run sound files at the same time. So basically as you said with instance of sound effect, I have to stop the last played sound then I can play a new one, but SoundEffect is the one which I'm looking for as it let me to play many sound files at the same time without having to stop them, the problem is that it starts lagging and sometimes it doesn't play sometime it does, I need to find out what exactly the problem is. I have tested it on different phones as well as emulator.

Comment: Colton, yes I realized that , its because I changed some files later so I had to change the names but I'll sort them later. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Nico Schertler is right! I've faced the same problem and fixed it by managing instances. Normally when you play soundeffect you always get the instance! By default you have to hope XNA/Monogame will care about it, but it doesn't. When you have to many live instances (even stopped, you get breaks, noise, even silence.

I hold rectangular array for all my sound effects with up to 4 instance for each, and if I have instances of a sound I want to play instead of creating I stop the oldest (by timestamp), play it and remember the current timestamp.

See the following code:

```
private const int MAX_INST_OF_ONE_SOUND = 4;
private SoundEffectInstance[][] sndInstArray = null;
private float[][] sndInstTimes = null;

public init()
{
    sndArray = new SoundEffect[SoundsSchema.sounds.Length];
    sndInstArray = new SoundEffectInstance[SoundsSchema.sounds.Length][];
    sndInstTimes = new float[SoundsSchema.sounds.Length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < SoundsSchema.sounds.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            sndArray[i] = content.Load<SoundEffect>(SoundsSchema.sounds[i]);//SoundsSchema is string list holder class
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }

        sndInstArray[i] = new SoundEffectInstance[MAX_INST_OF_ONE_SOUND];
        sndInstTimes[i] = new float[MAX_INST_OF_ONE_SOUND];
    }

}

private SoundEffectInstance getValidInstance(int sound)
{
    if (sound < 0 || sound > sndInstArray.Length)
        return null;

    SoundEffectInstance inst = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INST_OF_ONE_SOUND; i++)
    {
        if (sndInstArray[sound][i] == null || (sndInstArray[sound][i] != null && sndInstArray[sound][i].IsDisposed))
        {
            sndInstArray[sound][i] = sndArray[sound].CreateInstance();
            sndInstTimes[sound][i] = MyEngine.CurTime;
            inst = sndInstArray[sound][i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (inst == null)
    {
        float min_time = float.MaxValue;
        int ind = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INST_OF_ONE_SOUND; i++)
        {
            if (sndInstArray[sound][i] != null && sndInstTimes[sound][i] < min_time)
            {
                min_time = sndInstTimes[sound][i];
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        if (ind == -1)
            ind = 0;

        if (sndInstArray[sound][ind].IsDisposed)
            sndInstArray[sound][ind] = sndArray[sound].CreateInstance();
        else
        {
            try
            {
                sndInstArray[sound][ind].Stop();
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
        sndInstTimes[sound][ind] = MyEngine.CurTime;
        inst = sndInstArray[sound][ind];
    }

    return inst;
}



public virtual void playSound(int sound, float volume, float panoram, bool loop)
{
    if (sound < 0 || sound > sndArray.Length)
        return null;

    if (!mMuted && mVolume > 0)
    {
        SoundEffectInstance sndinst = getValidInstance(sound);
        if (sndinst == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            sndinst.IsLooped = loop;
            sndinst.Pan = panoram;
            sndinst.Volume = mVolume * vol;
            sndinst.Play();
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
    }
}
```